# ¿Cómo se ejecuta un if cuando se usa con una clausula AND?

Tags: condiciones, pascal

SI tengo esta condición:

`IF (("Condicion Uno") and ("Condicion Dos"))`

Si la "Condicion Uno" es falsa, el operador AND se fija también en la "Condicion Dos" o directamente no?

Se me vino esa duda el otro día.

Gracias por las respuestas, me falto especificar el lenguaje, el lenguaje es pascal.

Pd: pensé que todos los lenguajes lo evalúan de la misma manera, pero estaba equivocado.

Comment: DEPENDE de la implementación del lenguaje y del operador que se use. Hay casos en los que el intérprete comienza a evaluar y, si ve que es un AND, para al primer falso que encuentre.

Comment: Acá puedes usar la opción [edit] para editar tu pregunta todo lo que necesites y aclarar cosas.

Comment: Es mi primera post, gracias por aclarármelo para futuras publicaciones.

Comment: La cerre para evitar multiples posibles respuestas.. en realidad, se esta contestando una respuesta con lenguaje, en lugar de hacer una sola respuesta agnostica. La pregunta no es mala, pero en su formato actual, no hay respuesta correcto. Deberia ser agnostica.

Comment: Si el lenguaje es pascal, entonces pone pascal en una de las etiquetas, y por desgracias, tenemos que votar negativo a todas las respuestas, porque no responden la pregunta :/

Comment: No hay problema, ya con las respuestas que dieron, pude entender el concepto.

Comment: No es eso.. mas alla que te quedo claro, la pregunta recien ahora se ajusta a como funciona el sitio... pero no tenes una respuesta de que pasa en pascal...

Comment: @gbianchi Listo, jefazos. Espero que sirva la respuesta :)

Comment: Recuerda hacer el [tour] y aceptar la respuesta que sirva!

Answer (score 5):

### Respuesta a tu pregunta en Pascal

Para el caso específico de Pascal (FreePascal al menos), uno puede ver en [la documentación](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu46.html) que:

> **Remark** By default, boolean expressions are evaluated with short-circuit evaluation. This means that from the moment the result of the complete expression is known, evaluation is stopped and the result is returned. For instance, in the following expression:
>
> `B := True or MaybeTrue;`
>
> The compiler will never look at the value of MaybeTrue, since it is obvious that the expression will always be True. As a result of this strategy, if MaybeTrue is a function, it will not get called !

Que en español de la calle en latinoamérica dice que, si se llega a un punto en el que hay certeza del resultado, se detiene la evaluación de otras partes de la expresión lógica y se retorna el resultado. Si algo a la izquierda hace imposible obtener otra cosa, el valor que se tiene por cierto se retorna sin ir más allá.

Si `B := True or MaybeTrue;` se evalúa, el `True` a la izquierda hace imposible que B sea `False`, por lo que se procede a retornar `True` sin ocuparse jamás de lo que sea que hay en el lugar de `MaybeTrue`. Puede ser una función o una expresión anidada o cualquier otra cosa. Nunca se revisará.

### Algo de detalle sobre short-circuiting

Esta estrategia se conoce como [*short-circuiting*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluaci%C3%B3n_de_cortocircuito) (hacer corto circuito) y funciona como su simil eléctrico. Si la parte izquierda hace imposible que haya otro resultado, *el circuito se cierra en un lugar diferente al esperado, excluyendo todo lo demás* y se retorna el valor que corresponde sin siquiera gastar tiempo de procesador evaluando lo que sea que haya a la derecha de la expresión lógica.

Esta estrategia es popular pero no es ni mucho menos omnipresente. Es esencial revisar la documentación del lenguaje a usar para no suponer lo que pasa y escribir el código con certeza. Es posible encontrar en varios lenguajes, que hay disponibles *operadores de corto-circuito* (que permiten omitir el lado derecho dado el caso) y *operadores ansiosos* que odian pensar qué habría pasado si evaluaban algo, así que evalúan ambos lados sin importar nada.

Las expresiones lógicas tienen detalles de implementación particulares en este tipo de operaciones (el short-circuit que ves, la opción para asignar o no un valor por defecto a una variable dependiendo de una validación lógica, etc.). Resumen: ¡lee siempre la documentación para estar seguro!

A continuación, algunos ejemplos en otros lenguajes que recopilamos antes de que recordaras comentarnos que te interesaba sólo Pascal.

### PHP

Para PHP, los operadores lógicos de comparación [son *short-circuited*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Al menos para la versión actual (8.0), la documentación indica que

```
<?php

// --------------------
// El método foo() nunca será llamado, pues los operadores son short-circuit

$a = (false && foo());
$b = (true  || foo());
$c = (false and foo());
$d = (true  or  foo());
```

Existen las dos versiones de operadores AND y OR, se comportan igual en tanto no continúan la evaluación si el lado izquierdo no cumple, y sólo se diferencian en la precedencia (`&&` tiene mayor precedencia que `and`).

### Python

Para Python, encontramos en [la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) que:

> The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression x or y first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Que en español diría algo como que

- Al evaluar `x and y` primero evalúa `x`, si es `false` entonces retorna ese valor; en otro caso, evalúa `y` y el valor resultante de la operación lógica es lo que se retorna.
- La expresión `x or y` primero evalúa `x`; si es verdadero, retorna ese valor; en otro caso, evalúa `y` y retorna el valor de efectuar la operación lógica.

O sea, Python 3 hace *short-circuit*.

### C++

Para C++, hasta donde recuerdo, hay unos operadores (`+` para OR, `*` para AND) que garantizan evaluar ambos lados de la expresión:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void imprimir(bool y)
{
    cout << boolalpha << y << endl;
}

int main() 
{
    imprimir(true + false);
    imprimir(true * false);
}
```

Eso entregaría:

```
true

false
```

PD. Heh, esto está puesto tal cual [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1758941/236345). En ese mismo hilo indican que, teniendo dos operandos `bool`, se puede usar `&` para AND y no hace short-circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Eso se conoce como [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) o evaluación de corto circuito (en mi frágil intento de traducir el término) en donde efectivamente algunos operadores lógicos (como `AND` en este caso) evalúan la segunda condición solo si la primera se cumple dependiendo de la estrategia de evaluación que use el lenguaje de programación ([lazy vs eager evaluation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/functional_programming_with_java/functional_programming_with_java_evaluation.htm#:%7E:text=Eager%20evaluation%20means%20expression%20is,of%20an%20expression%20when%20needed.)).

Una prueba rápida con Javascript por ejemplo sería la siguiente:

```js
function fn(val, log) {
    console.log(log);
    return val;
}

fn(false, '1.1 evaluated') && fn(false, '1.2 evaluated');
fn(true, '2.1 evaluated') && fn(false, '2.2 evaluated');
```

Comment: La pregunta, es sobre pascal..

Comment: @gbianchi no lo especificó en la pregunta original...

Comment: por eso, te lo aclare.. paso en todas las respuestas ;). Y por eso tu respuesta quedo desactualizada...

Answer (score -1):

La respuesta a esta pregunta puede variar de lenguaje en lenguaje, en mi caso puedo responderte desde mi experiencia con Javascript y PHP. En estos lenguajes no, la segunda condición no se evalúa si la primera condición es falsa al utilizar el operador AND.

Saludos.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Answer (score -2):

Solo si la primera condición es true pasa a la segunda condicion y sus sucesivamente.
Caso contrario que pasa con el "or", en este operado se evalúan todas las condiciones

Comment: Depende de la implementacion del lenguaje